# EXCEL PIVOT TABLE - Common timeline for multiple date fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

In EXCEL 2016, I have a Pivot table, from my Power Pivot data model, that regroups different related tables:
My tables are real sales, declared sales, timesheets from beauty advisors, & activities performed by these beauty advisors that are all linked to my stores table.

I added multiple timelines to filter date fields in these different tables, in order to track our KPIs. My problem is that I am having multiple timelines when I'd only need one common timeline to filter all these date fields.

[image: Timelines Example]

Actually, when declared sales timeline is filtered to Jan 19 for example, Real sales timeline, & activities timeline should also be filtered to Jan 19 as we are comparing results.

Is there a way to merge these timelines into one timeline? Or have one timeline control the other ones, and having them hidden in the background? If possible I'd like to avoid VBA..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Power Pivot, the easiest thing to do is to create a separate Date table. You can then link the Date columns of your fact tables with the Date column in your date table. Afterwards, you create a timeline with the column in the Date table and because of the links with your fact tables, they get filtered automatically.

I think this link shows a pretty good way of creating the date table and link it:
https://www.excel-university.com/one-click-data-model-date-table/

Comment: Hey Alex, Thanks that did the job perfectly. I had no idea there was a calendar table in Power Pivot. I upvoted your answer